# The preinstall npm script of coa package throws "Cannot find module '/Users/dulin/workspace/xxx/xxx-m/node_modules/coa/compile.js'" error

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try to execute `npm audit fix` command, got error:

```sh
> coa@2.1.3 preinstall /Users/dulin/workspace/xxx/xxx-m/node_modules/coa
> start /B node compile.js & node compile.js

sh: start: command not found
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/dulin/workspace/xxx/xxx-m/node_modules/coa/compile.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I had read this question: [Cannot find module coa/compile.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69839972/cannot-find-module-coa-compile-js). But none of the answers work for me.

My project doesn't use `coa` package as dependency directly, I found it used by `svgo` package and `svgo` package used by `postcss-svgo` package in `package-lock.json`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try: "Force use of v2.0.2 via resolutions in package.json:
`... "resolutions": {
      "coa": "2.0.2"
    }, ...`
For yarn is out-of-the-box. For npm install, add to package.json:

`"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "([ ! -f package-lock.json ] && npm install --package-lock-only --ignore-scripts --no-audit); npx npm-force-resolutions", ...`"

Answer (score 0):

Please urgently check this thread as coa package was hijacked and malicious code was injected

https://github.com/veged/coa/issues/99

and here also

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/popular-coa-npm-library-hijacked-to-steal-user-passwordsu/